# Call other scripts with source and make the call conditional with if statements

Tags: bash, source

I have an rsync script which I have on various servers. Rather than re-writing it for specifics on each VM I thought of creting other scripts for the specifics and calling them with `source`. I'd thought of putting the `source` in an `if` statement like so;

```
# Check for Atlassian Apps
if [[ "$SERVER_NAME=crowd.server.com" ]]; then
  # call crowd-bkup.sh
  echo -e "\e[1mCrowd backup running ...\e[0m"
  SCRIPTDIR=$(dirname "$0")
  # shellcheck source=src/crowd-bkup.sh
  # shellcheck disable=SC1091
  source "${SCRIPTDIR}/crowd-bkup.sh"
```

My question is how do I add more for the likes of my Confluence, Jira servers etc.? Is it possible to add them without adding a load more `if` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[ "$SERVER_NAME=crowd.server.com" ]]` is always true (it tests if `$SERVER_NAME=crowd.server.com` expands to a non-empty string). You meant `[[ "$SERVER_NAME" = "crowd.server.com" ]]`.

If you want to perform different processing for different server names then you can use `case`:

```
case "$SERVER_NAME" in
  crowd.server.com)
    echo -e "\e[1mCrowd backup running ...\e[0m"
    …
    ;;
  jira.server.com)
    echo -e "\e[1mJira backup running ...\e[0m"
    …
    ;;
  …
esac
```

If you want to execute the same command for multiple names, you can use multiple patterns separated by `|`. You can use shell wildcards in the patterns, e.g.

```
case "$SERVER_NAME" in
  crowd.server.com|jira.server.com)
    echo -e "\e[1mBackup running in ${SERVER_NAME%.*}...\e[0m"
    …
    ;;
  *.mysubdomain.server.com)
    echo -e "\e[1mBackup running in mysubdomain...\e[0m"
    …
    ;;
  …
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with an array and wrapping the if inside a for loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

names=( crowd horde host army pack )

for n in "${names[2]}"; do
    # Check for Atlassian Apps
    if [[ "$SERVER_NAME=crowd.server.com" ]]; then
        # call "${n}-bkup.sh"
        echo -e "\e[1m$n backup running ...\e[0m"
        SCRIPTDIR=$(dirname "$0")
    # shellcheck source="src/$n-bkup.sh"
    # shellcheck disable=SC1091
    source "${SCRIPTDIR}/$n-bkup.sh"
done
```

Or, using the positional arguments:

```
set -- crowd horde host army pack
for $n; do
    .....
done
```